# Sample Average Approximation vs. Numerical Integration

Tags: optimization, numerics, integration, monte-carlo

To calculate the expected value of objective functions, we have two choices:

1. Sample Average Approximation (SAA):
   $$
   \frac{1}{N}\sum_{i=1}^N f(x,\xi^i).
   $$
2. Numerical Integration (e.g., Monte Carlo method):
   $$
   \frac{1}{N} \sum_{\xi^i\in\Xi^N}^N f(x,\xi^i)p(\xi^i),
   $$
   where $p(\cdot)$ is a probability density function and $\Xi^N\subset\Xi$ is the approximation of the support $\Xi$ of the probability function.

The value of SAA converges to the true expectation ($\mathbb{E}[f(x,\xi)]$) as $N\to\infty$, as does the numerical integration, due to the law of large numbers. However, from the numerical viewpoint, what is the difference between these two methods?

More specifically, in stochastic optimization or expected residual minimization of the least squared mean for a system of equations, how do these methods differ in convergence rate?

Comment: Hint: The first example can be interpreted as the second example using p=1.